# O que uma classe "Thread Safety" significa?

Tags: c#, .net, thread, owin

De acordo com o `MSDN` a [WebApp Class (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.hosting.webapp(v=vs.113).aspx) é `Thread Safety`. O que isso significa exatamente?

Esta classe especificamente tem um método `Start` que:

> Inicia uma web app....

Cada requisição a  esse `app` seria manipulador por uma `Thread`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O artigo não diz que a classe é "`thread safety`", este é um título da seção que diz:

Qualquer membro estático púbico desta classe é "`thread safe`", ou seja, pode ser manipulado por várias tarefas simultaneamente.

Também há a informação que qualquer instância da classe (objetos criados desta classe) não teem garantia de serem `thread safe`. Instâncias da classe não devem ser utilizadas por várias tarefas simultaneamente.

Neste caso específico, significa que várias tarefas podem usar as implementações do método `Start` simultaneamente, cada chamada ao método não causa problemas nas outras chamadas.

Comment: Também há a informação que a classe é estática, portanto não tem instâncias dela.

Comment: Bem observado, a declaração da classe define ela como estática, então não é possível criar instâncias dela. E mais: na declaração em C++ há ainda o flag `sealed`, que impede que ela seja utilizada como classe ancestral de outras classes, ou seja, nem fazendo outra classe e herdando dela! Não me lembro mais de C#, mas na declaração em C# não tem este flag.

Comment: Porque classes estáticas são automaticamente `sealed`. E lembrando que aquilo é C++/CLI, não existe este atributo em C++ puro.

Answer (score 2):

Significa que os membros estáticos desta classe podem operar sem problemas através de múltiplas *threads*. Eles não possuem nada que possa causar problemas quando roda de forma concorrente ou se possui alguma situação que possa causar problemas, eles já possuem um mecanismo que não deixa nenhum problema ocorrer. Então você pode acessar estes membros de forma concorrente sem medo.

Mas os membros das instâncias não são garantidos como *thread safe*. O que não importa neste caso, já que a classe é estática.

Se fosse uma classe instanciável você ainda poderia usar as instâncias de forma concorrente se providenciar mecanismos que garantem o bom funcionamento concorrentemente. Ou ainda poderá usar de forma paralela mas não concorrente.

É claro que programação usando *threads* não é algo simples, você ainda precisa saber o que está fazendo mesmo que tudo da classe seja *thread safe*.

Classes estáticas não costumam ser usadas mais de uma vez na aplicação. Embora nada impeça que seja feito, esta não parece ser o caso, ela parece ser algo que deva ser única na aplicação. Portanto, de uma forma geral, não se usa ela com *threads*. Pelo menos é o meu entendimento lendo a pouca documentação. [Veja o exemplo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).