# O que é uma função reentrante?

Tags: funções, terminologia, ciência-da-computação

Para que ela serve? Quando ela é reentrante? Qual é a diferença para uma função recursiva? E para a função *thread safe*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função reentrante é aquela que pode ser chamada de forma segura várias vezes concorrentemente sem causar efeitos indesejáveis. Ela precisa ser independente, e não ser afetada mesmo que haja interrupção na execução.

Uma [função recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323954/101) pode ser reentrante, mas nem sempre. Não há necessidade de função reentrante ser recursiva.

Certamente uma função reentrante é [*thread safe*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76758/101), mas não são sinônimos, porque uma função *thread safe* ainda pode ter [efeitos colaterais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101).

Uma função reentrante é [pura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255557/101), em certa medida. Então além dela não poder modificar estado externo a ela, a não ser que tenha alguma proteção adequada para garantir a atomicidade da operação de forma isolada, ela também não pode se modificar, e só pode chamar outras funções reentrantes. Então ela pode ser menos pura, desde que dê certas garantias.

Apenas proteger um objeto com *mutex* em [estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101) ou algo do tipo, pode não ser suficiente. Se uma interrupção no processo para executar alguma outra coisa afetar o funcionamento do que estava fazendo então não há reentrância. A garantia de sincronização pode ser feita na função reentrante ou de forma global pela aplicação.

A forma mais fácil que garantir reentrância é ela ser totalmente pura, ainda que não precise, caso contrário terá que fazer uma análise profunda para garantir que nada será afetado em ambiente concorrente.

Exemplo de reentrância simples:

```
void swap(int* x, int* y) {
    int tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp; //Hardware interrompe e chama a isr()
}
void isr() {
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    swap(&x, &y);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Reentrant.c).

Note que nada será afetado, a nova chamada é completamente independente e não afeta o resultado do que estava fazendo, os parâmetros de uma chamada não se confundem com os da segunda chamada.

Código puramente funcional é sempre reentrante, mas em código imperativo, ainda mais orientado a objeto, quase sempre não é, e necessita análise se precisa garantir a reentrância.

Comment: Então "reentrante" seria o que, em inglês, chamam de *idempotent*? Ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226232

Comment: Não, seria *reentrant*, até porque não é o mesmo que idempotente que é um requisito para ser reentrante.

Comment: Entendi. E idempotência também não implica nada a respeito de concorrência.

Comment: Certamente, grosso modo a reentrância é um *superset* de idempotente.